# Unable to keep data in form after submitting

Tags: php, html, web

I've been searching online on how to keep data in the form after submitting it. But after trying for awhile it still doesn't work as expected

This is the code that I tried:

```
<form action="process_login" method="post" target="_self">
  <div class="login-field">
    <input type="text" id="login-email-field" name="login-email-field" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["login-email-field"]) ? $_POST["login-email-field"] : ''; ?>" required />
    <label class="login-email-label" for="login-email-field">Email/Username</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="submit-button" type="submit">
      Login
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I also tried replacing the input (with a 'TEST' string in the value field if the POST is empty) but the 'TEST' string did not appear after submitting the form.

```
<input type="text" id="login-email-field" name="login-email-field" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["login-email-field"]) ? $_POST["login-email-field"] : 'TEST'; ?>" required />
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Use var_dump($_POST);` in your script and log the contents of the POST data after the form was submitted, then you know what you're actually working with

Comment: @ADyson Apparently the POST data is an empty array, how do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you viewed it after submitting the form, not just when you load the page initially?

Comment: P.s. how are you actually submitting this form? There doesn't seem to be a submit button

Comment: @ADyson Kinda new to PHP, I feel like I didn't do it right but all I did was add a `print_r(var_dump($_POST))` at the end of the file and submitted the form and see if it contained anything. I also edited the post to include the submit button

Comment: You don't use print_r _and_ var_dump in the same command...you can just use one or the other, they do a very similar job (check the docs)

Answer (score 0):

Action specifies a URL to which the form’s data is sent when submitted.
If you want to stay on the same page you can leave it out

```
<form method="post" target="_self">
```

or set the name of the actual page.

```
<form action="actualPage.php" method="post" target="_self">
```

Comment: yea the `proccess_login` is actually `proccess_login.php`, my `.htaccess` file makes it such that they are the same.

The form does get processed just that on the same page the _$POST is empty

Comment: For me your code snippet works now. Please look in the other part of your code if the id "login-email-field" or the name "login-email-field" of the input field is used.